# Use attribute in unicode string in Django template

Tags: django

I have a model where I use a TextField() to store JSON data. Let say there is the following data in this field called json_data:

```
{"name":"alex","surname":"grs","type":"warrior"}
```

In my template I am trying to access attribute from my json_data object but without success (template thinks this json_data is a unicode string and not an iterable object.

```
{{json_data.name}} # empty
{{json_data.surname}} # empty
{{json_data}} # print {"name":"alex","surname":"grs","type":"warrior"}
```

Do you have an idea how I can access those attributes? I would like to transform it in a python object but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to deserialize it, in the view.

```
json_data = json.loads(my_json_string)
```

You should probably consider using one of the many third-party JSONField implementations, which would take care of deserializing the data when you load the model and serializing it again when you save.

Comment: I used JSONField before but I had an issue with a south migration... :s